# Using code snippets as 'functions' of sorts in a web developer's IDE?

Tags: ide, code-snippets

ok so this is somewhat of an awkward question, but lets put it like this...

I have a website with about 15 pages... Thanks to HTML5, I have a distinct  and  for the site. The content in these sections is fairly complex (with navigation menus and what not).

Now here's the problem, on Monday, (when I completed the site) everything was fine. On Wednesday, I realized that I need to add another item to the navigation menu in the , and change the parameters of some elements in the ...

Any simplistic way of doing this, other than editing one file, and then copy/pasting into each and every other file manually one by one?

Is there a good IDE out there that will allow me to just add a  as a snippet in many places, and if I edit the master snippet, it auto-changes everywhere else?

Hope I'm being clear here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well… first thought: is server side scripting out of question? If so, maybe server side includes can be utilized? Whichever IDE you'd use, it'd solve only part
 of the problem, leaving real architectural problem untouched.

Comment: Server side scripting isn't out of the question, its just... "Out of reach"... Lets just say I've been developing for like, 2 1/2 months now, and I've gotten comfortable with client side development, but I haven't ventured into the server side just yet... I'd like to be thorough with the front bend before I take it to the back... :-)

Comment: I hindsight, utilizing server side scripting is possibly the easiest solution... For now... :-/

Comment: It's a life saver in situations requiring repeating fragments of markup. If you don't want to dive into more complex (and flexible) solutions you may want to look at Server Side Includes – it should ease you pain ;)

Comment: I meant server side scripting... they are both more complex and more flexible than server side includes which pretty much paste designated files into specific places in requested file. Take o look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes